# Join on table to get TOP 1 Date SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

This the old way cause I had one record

```
SET @ThepriorPurge = (SELECT TOP 1 TNP.[updated_Time]
                      FROM [dbo].[udt_LP_Purge] AS TNP,
                            @tempFCPurgeOrder AS TCP
                      WHERE tcp.Item = TNP.Item
                        AND TNP.Updated_Time < tcp.updated_Time
                        AND TNP.Locn = @destinationTank
                      ORDER BY TNP.Updated_Time DESC)
```

I'm trying to convert to a table to join and keep getting multiple values of the 
min date time.

`@tempFCPurgeOrder`:

```
Row Item    updated_time    LOCN
-------------------------------------
1   4732    3/10/18 8:34    Tank1
2   4732    3/11/18 15:36   Tank1
3   4732    3/12/18 12:39   Tank1
4   4732    3/14/18 9:19    Tank1
5   7812    3/7/18 14:42    Tank2
6   7812    3/19/18 14:35   Tank2
```

`[udt_LOTP_Purge]`:

```
Row Item    updated_Time    LOCN
---------------------------------
1   4732    3/9/18 8:34     Tank1
2   4732    3/10/18 15:36   Tank1
3   4732    3/13/18 12:39   Tank1
4   4732    3/13/18 9:19    Tank1
5   7812    3/5/18 15:42    Tank2
6   7812    3/15/18 15:42   Tank2
```

- Record a 1 should match 1
- Record a 2 should match 2
- Record a 3 should match 2

However all items 4732 and tank 1 match table b row 1.

I don't have row ids on the table,  just there for examples

Comment: Sorry, but so hard to understand you after reading twice. Can you please make it more clear so we can help you?

Comment: Can you please clearly show what is your expected output?

Comment: Help us help you.  No one can help you if no one can understand you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the max updated time per tank and item?

```
SELECT tnp.Locn, tnp.Item, MAX(tnp.Updated_Time) Updated_Time
FROM dbo.udt_LP_Purge AS tnp
GROUP BY tnp.Locn, tnp.Item
```